# Text Highlight using Xpath

Tags: javascript

I am highlighting selected text by using the following xpath and offsets.

Here is an **example** selection of text I am using to debug.

```
[{
  commonAncestorContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]",
  startContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]",
  startOffset:0,
  endContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]",
  endOffset:1,
  color: "purple"
}]
```

This selection above **works nicely** and highlights the selected paragraph.
Now here is **the part I am stuck on**, as soon as I **add text to the paragraph** it fails to highlight the text.

Here is the example with selected paragraph and text, so in theory this should only select the text inside the paragraph that you selected. **Changes are marked in bold**

[{
  commonAncestorContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]**/text()[0]**",
  startContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]**/text()[0]**",
  **startOffset:288**,
  endContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]**/text()[0]**",
  **endOffset:330**,
  color: "purple"
}]

---

#### test.html

(this uses highlight.show)

```
function highlightTest() {
        $MON.highlight.show([
            {
                commonAncestorContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0001]",
                startContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0001]",
                startOffset:0,
                endContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0001]",
                endOffset:1,
                color: "yellow"
            },
            {
                commonAncestorContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[0]",
                startContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[0]",
                startOffset:288,
                endContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[0]",
                endOffset:330,
                color: "purple"
            }
        ]);
```

---

#### highlight.js

(this uses xpath.element)

```
show: function(selections) 
{
        for (var i in selections) 
        {
            var selection = selections[i];

            var ancestor = $MON.xpath.element(selection["commonAncestorContainer"]);                            
            ancestor.contentEditable = "true";

            var col = selection["color"] ? selection["color"] : "yellow";
            var range = document.createRange();

            var startElement = $MON.xpath.element(selection["startContainer"]);            
            var startOffset = selection["startOffset"];            

            var endElement = $MON.xpath.element(selection["endContainer"]);            
            var endOffset = selection["endOffset"];            

            range.setStart(startElement, startOffset);
            range.setEnd(endElement, endOffset);

            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);

            document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, col);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            ancestor.contentEditable = "false";
       }
 }
```

---

**xpath.js**
(this returns the corresponding element given the xpath, back to highlight.js)

```
element: function (expr) {
        var resolver = function (prefix) {
            if ("xhtml" == prefix) {
                return "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
            }
        }

        var result = document.evaluate(expr, document, resolver, 9, null).singleNodeValue;
        return result;
    }
```

---

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <p>
      1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tellus ligula, ullamcorper vitae elementum sed, rhoncus a ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et pulvinar augue. Proin non semper mi. Nullam justo velit, vehicula eu congue vitae, tincidunt sit amet urna. Aliquam blandit rutrum dignissim. Donec dapibus nisl arcu, eu eleifend tellus lobortis quis. Praesent quis hendrerit diam. Quisque ultricies lorem et turpis aliquam ornare. Phasellus dolor purus, lacinia eget porta vel, iaculis ac nisl. Phasellus vestibulum faucibus erat sit amet interdum.
    </p>
    <p>
      2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tellus ligula, ullamcorper vitae elementum sed, rhoncus a ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et pulvinar augue. Proin non semper mi. Nullam justo velit, vehicula eu congue vitae, tincidunt sit amet urna. Aliquam blandit rutrum dignissim. Donec dapibus nisl arcu, eu eleifend tellus lobortis quis. Praesent quis hendrerit diam. Quisque ultricies lorem et turpis aliquam ornare. Phasellus dolor purus, lacinia eget porta vel, iaculis ac nisl. Phasellus vestibulum faucibus erat sit amet interdum.
    </p>
    <p>
      3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tellus ligula, ullamcorper vitae elementum sed, rhoncus a ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et pulvinar augue. Proin non semper mi. Nullam justo velit, vehicula eu congue vitae, tincidunt sit amet urna. Aliquam blandit rutrum dignissim. Donec dapibus nisl arcu, eu eleifend tellus lobortis quis. Praesent quis hendrerit diam. Quisque ultricies lorem et turpis aliquam ornare. Phasellus dolor purus, lacinia eget porta vel, iaculis ac nisl. Phasellus vestibulum faucibus erat sit amet interdum.
    </p>
    <p>
      4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tellus ligula, ullamcorper vitae elementum sed, rhoncus a ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et pulvinar augue. Proin non semper mi. Nullam justo velit, vehicula eu congue vitae, tincidunt sit amet urna. Aliquam blandit rutrum dignissim. Donec dapibus nisl arcu, eu eleifend tellus lobortis quis. Praesent quis hendrerit diam. Quisque ultricies lorem et turpis aliquam ornare. Phasellus dolor purus, lacinia eget porta vel, iaculis ac nisl. Phasellus vestibulum faucibus erat sit amet interdum.
    </p>
    <p>
      5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tellus ligula, ullamcorper vitae elementum sed, rhoncus a ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et pulvinar augue. Proin non semper mi. Nullam justo velit, vehicula eu congue vitae, tincidunt sit amet urna. Aliquam blandit rutrum dignissim. Donec dapibus nisl arcu, eu eleifend tellus lobortis quis. Praesent quis hendrerit diam. Quisque ultricies lorem et turpis aliquam ornare. Phasellus dolor purus, lacinia eget porta vel, iaculis ac nisl. Phasellus vestibulum faucibus erat sit amet interdum.
    </p>
    <p>
      6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tellus ligula, ullamcorper vitae elementum sed, rhoncus a ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et pulvinar augue. Proin non semper mi. Nullam justo velit, vehicula eu congue vitae, tincidunt sit amet urna. Aliquam blandit rutrum dignissim. Donec dapibus nisl arcu, eu eleifend tellus lobortis quis. Praesent quis hendrerit diam. Quisque ultricies lorem et turpis aliquam ornare. Phasellus dolor purus, lacinia eget porta vel, iaculis ac nisl. Phasellus vestibulum faucibus erat sit amet interdum.
    </p>

</body>
```

---

**Log on text selection, gets the selected xpath**

```
38:Selected text: Lorem
44:Collapsed: false
45:Ancestor container: /xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[0001]
46:Start container: /xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[0001]
47:Start offset: 7
48:End container: /xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[0001]
49:End offset: 12
```

**Update (my problem was)**


I had to add

> document.designMode = "on";

before i set the hilite color
here is a link to js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/E2BbX/11/

Comment: Generally, using `for .. in` to iterate an array is frowned upon. Don't do it, use a proper `for` loop or a dedicated array iterator function from your favorite JS framework.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip, ill add a proper for loop for that iteration

Comment: The reason is that `for .. in` iterates all object properties, for arrays this is all of the array's indexes *and* any custom properties that might have been added. `for .. in` might work or break at run-time depending on how the passed object looks like, so it's good practice to play it safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath indexes are one-based. Try

```
startContainer: "/xhtml:html[0001]/xhtml:body[0001]/xhtml:p[0002]/text()[1]
```

and so on.

Comment: ive tried text(), text()[0], text()[1], text()[01], text()[001], text()[0001] to no avail

Comment: Without seeing the HTML involved it's impossible to tell. The one thing to say for sure is that if `text()[1]` does not return anything, then there is no child text node there. (Also, trying `[1]` and `[01]` and `[001]` really doesn't make sense. If `[1]` gives you nothing, why would equivalent expressions behave any different?)

Comment: very basic html with a couple of paragraphs, let me add it for you

Comment: I will also add my log on selection, when I select text it shows the correct elements with text inside <p>

Comment: I'm sorry, but this works. http://jsfiddle.net/E2BbX/ You must make a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: I see what you mean, it does in fact get hold of the element. thanks!